# decoding shift-jis: "illegal multibyte sequence"

Tags: python, encoding, hex, decode, shift-jis

I'm trying to decode a shift-jis encoded string, like this:

```
string.decode('shift-jis').encode('utf-8')
```

to be able to view it in my program.

When I come across 2 shift-jis characters, in hex "0x87 0x54" and "0x87 0x55", I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: illegal multibyte sequence
```

But I'm sure they are valid shift-jis characters: http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml

I've also noticed that those characters appear as black boxes in my shift-jis text editor, which means they are not recognized. So there's something special about these two chars that made my editor and Python decoder fail. Help?

(sorry, I couldn't post an example string because when those characters are present, it doesn't get added to the clipboard from there onward and also gets converted to unicode automatically. I posted the hex values for them though.)

Answer (score 9):

Multiple versions of Shift JIS exist. The `shift_jis` codec is [JIS X 0208](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0208), whereas that table is [JIS X 0213](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0213), corresponding to the `shift_jisx0213` codec.

```
>>> u'⑲⑳Ⅰ'.encode('shift_jisx0213')
'\x87R\x87S\x87T'
```

Comment: Add some [infomation](http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~ax2s-kmtn/character/japan.html) on Shift-JIS encoding.

Comment: It basically works. However if the source text is Shift-JIS generated by Windows includes 0x80, try 'cp932' instead.

Comment: Actually very few Japanese text use 'Shift_JISX0213'. It is not used in Windows (ja-JP), which is the last popular environment reading&writing Shift_JIS. See details in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You should never use `shift_jisx0213`. It has never been used for actual production purposes. Windows cannot handle it. The character set JIS X 0213 is used with Unicode in most cases but not with Shift_JIS encoding.

Use `'cp932'` (in Python 3).

./sjis.txt contains

```
5c  7e  87  52  87  53  87  54  87  8a  fa  b1  fb  50  fb  fc
```

(They are \~⑲⑳Ⅰ㈱﨑瀨髙 saved on Windows 10)

```
>>> import codecs
>>> codecs.open('sjis.txt',"rb",'shift_jis').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 700, in read
    return self.reader.read(size)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'shift_jis' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 2: illegal multibyte sequence
>>> codecs.open('sjis.txt',"rb",'shift_jisx0213').read()
'¥‾⑲⑳Ⅰ㈱郫鍚騠'
>>> codecs.open('sjis.txt',"rb",'cp932').read()
'\\~⑲⑳Ⅰ㈱﨑瀨髙'
```

`shift_jisx0213` decodes symbols and the last three kanjis incorrectly.