# Convert encoding of a csv file from utf-8 to shift-jis in python

Tags: python, utf-8, copy, shift-jis

I have a CSV file with utf-8 encoding. I want to change it's to shift-jis csv file using python code. Is it possible? How can i do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729016/decoding-shift-jis-illegal-multibyte-sequence

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like task for [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) (it is part of standard library). Two [`codecs.open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) might be used if you want to just change encoding following way

```
import codecs
with codecs.open("file1.csv","r",encoding="utf_8") as fin:
    with codecs.open("file2.csv","w",encoding="shift_jis") as fout:
        fout.write(fin.read())
```

above code assumes that you have UTF-8 encoded file `file1.csv` and what to create shitf-jis encoded `file2.csv` and you have enough RAM space free to load whole file there. Be warned that in [Standard Encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) following shift_jis encoding are available

- shift_jis
- shift_jis_2004
- shift_jisx0213

I do not know difference between them, so you would need yourself which one you actually need to use.

Comment: Daweo, Thanks.
shift_jis_2004 and shift_jisx0213 working fine. however, some of the characters are incorrect. Like Hyphen not converted correctly

UTF 8 date: 線－総司
Shift data : 線・総司

Comment: `codecs` is not needed. Built-in `open` has the same `encoding` parameter.